# Passing data to the mapper

Tags: database, hadoop

I have a few databases which are not JDBC enabled but I am able to retrieve data from these DBs. I want to pass this data to the mapper in a mapreduce program. I tried hard to figure out things from the source files present in "mapreduce.lib.DB" package but I feel am missing something. Can anyone kindly tell me how can I pass the output of the database to the mapper ?

Comment: You need to be more explicit on what help is needed !!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [Sqoop](http://sqoop.apache.org/) for that.

First You have to transfer your data from rdbms to hdfs by using `sqoop import` command.

Later You will write a mapreduce program which will take input path as parameter for the method `setInputpath`.

Answer (score 0):

One easy way is to bulk export the data from the DB into a file, put the file in HDFS and the use the [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/input/FileInputFormat.html) to read the file in HDFS and process it.

Comment: I actually want to run a mapreduce program on top of this database just like we run a mapreduce prog on top of mysql or any other database. So taking the data from the DB to a file in HDFS is not performance efficient. Kindly suggest if there is any other way by which I can pass this data to the mapper ?